# ABRecordCopyValue and ABPropertyID crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, abaddressbook

I'm trying to retrieve data from the iPhone address book and I have some problems.

First of all, I have an array of all contacts (`self.allContacts`):

```
ABAddressBookRef abRef = ABAddressBookCreate();     
self.allContacts = (NSMutableArray*)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(abRef);
```

I also have an array of all properties (each property as string) called `self.allKeys`.

The crash occurs when I try to get the properties using a property from `self.allKeys`:

```
NSString *currentRecord = [[NSString alloc] init];
ABRecordRef currentRecordRef;
ABPropertyID currentFieldProperty;

currentRecordRef =  (ABRecordRef)[self.allContacts objectAtIndex:i];
currentFieldProperty = (ABPropertyID)[self.allKeys objectAtIndex:j];

currentRecord = (NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(currentRecordRef, currentFieldProperty);
```

The problem is that passing `currentFieldProperty` to `ABRecordCopyValue` causes a crash.

---

- `self.allContacts` is an array of all contacts
- `self.allKeys` is an array of all properties (each property as string)

When trying to retrieve a single property from `ABRecordCopyValue` it causes an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` crash.

Thanks!

Comment: You haven't mentioned how self.allKeys is being populated. Also, is there any useful information you get upon crash?

Comment: self.allKeys is an array that holds all ABPropertyID properties such as kABPersonFirstNameProperty

I don't receive any log when it's crash

Comment: How do you know specifically that ABRecordCopyValue causes the crash? Do you get EXC_BAD_ACCESS? SIGBRT? Anything at all that might shed some light on the matter?

Comment: Yes, I do receive EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: Have you tried running your app with NSZombieEnabled?

Comment: hmm... How about running it line by line and making sure all the passed references are valid before the call to ABRecordCopyValue?

Comment: I would especially give thought to the value of currentFieldProperty - because it is taken out of a dictionary, it is an object but the function is supposed to receive an enumerated value. Maybe try currentFieldProperty = (ABPropertyID)[[self.allKeys objectAtIndex:j] intValue];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set [NSZombieEnabled](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled), [MallocStackLogging](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MallocStackLogging), and [guard malloc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html) in the debugger.  Then, when your App crashes, type this in the gdb console:

```
(gdb) info malloc-history 0x543216
```

Replace 0x543216 with the address of the object that caused the crash, and you will get a much more useful stack trace and it should help you pinpoint the exact line in your code that is causing the problem.

---

- More thoughts -

If `self.allKeys` is indeed

> "an array of all properties (each property as string)"

then you should probably get the `intValue` of the array object (property) since an `ABPropertyID` is just a `typedef int32_t`.  Something like:

```
currentFieldProperty = (ABPropertyID)[[self.allKeys objectAtIndex:j] intValue];
ABRecordCopyValue(currentRecordRef, currentFieldProperty)
```

But we would need to see the values in `self.allKeys` or how it is populated to be sure.

From [ABRecordRef Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AddressBook/Reference/ABRecordRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html) and [CFTypeRef Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFTypeRef/Reference/reference.html)

> `ABRecordCopyValue` - *Returns the value of a record property.*
>
> ```
>     CFTypeRef ABRecordCopyValue (
>        ABRecordRef record,
>        ABPropertyID property
>     );
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>   `record` - *The record containing the property in question.*
>   `property` - *The property of record whose value is being returned.*
>
> **Return Value**
>   *The value of property in record.*

And:

> `ABPropertyID` - *Integer that identifies a record property.*
>   `typedef int32_t ABPropertyID;`

---

- And more troubleshooting ideas -

If the above is not the case, then your crash may be caused when you cast `CFTypeRef` to `NSString *` in `(NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(currentRecordRef, currentFieldProperty)` so here is a little helper function that might solve that:

```
- (NSString*)stringValueForCFType:(CFTypeRef)cfValue {
    NSString *stringValue = nil;
    if (!cfValue) return nil;
    CFTypeID cfType = CFGetTypeID(cfValue);
    if (cfType == CFStringGetTypeID()) {
        stringValue = [[(id)CFMakeCollectable(cfValue) retain] autorelease];
    } else if (cfType == CFURLGetTypeID()) {
        stringValue = [(NSURL*)cfValue absoluteString];
    } else if (cfType == CFNumberGetTypeID()) {
        stringValue = [(NSNumber*)cfValue stringValue];
    } else if (cfType == CFNullGetTypeID()) {
        stringValue = [NSString string];
    } else if (cfType == AXUIElementGetTypeID()) {
        stringValue = [[GTMAXUIElement elementWithElement:cfValue] description];
    } else if (cfType == AXValueGetTypeID()) {
        stringValue = [self stringValueForAXValue:cfValue];
    } else if (cfType == CFArrayGetTypeID()) {
        stringValue = [self stringValueForCFArray:cfValue];
    } else if (cfType == CFBooleanGetTypeID()) {
        stringValue = CFBooleanGetValue(cfValue) ? @"YES" : @"NO";
    } else {
        CFStringRef description = CFCopyDescription(cfValue);
        stringValue = [(id)CFMakeCollectable(description) autorelease];
  }
  return stringValue;       
}
```

Then do `currentRecord = [self stringValueForCFType:ABRecordCopyValue(currentRecordRef, currentFieldProperty)];` and check to make sure `self.allKeys` has an object at index `j` and `self.allContacts` has an object at index `i`:

```
NSString *currentRecord = [[NSString alloc] init];
ABRecordRef currentRecordRef;
ABPropertyID currentFieldProperty;

if (self.allContacts.count > i) {
    currentRecordRef = (ABRecordRef)[self.allContacts objectAtIndex:i];    
    if (self.allKeys.count > j) {
        currentFieldProperty = (ABPropertyID)[self.allKeys objectAtIndex:j];
        currentRecord = [self stringValueForCFType:ABRecordCopyValue(currentRecordRef, currentFieldProperty)];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"self.allKeys has no value at index (%d): %@", j, [allKeys description]);
    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"self.allContacts has no value at index (%d): %@", i, [allContacts description]);
}
```

---

Edit (regarding the comments):

To convert string of property name to its int value, you need to create the following (this probably is not be the correct order that they need to be in, so `NSLog` them first to see what order they need to be in):

```
NSString * const ABPropertyID_toString[] = {
    @"kABPersonFirstNameProperty",
    @"kABPersonLastNameProperty",
    @"kABPersonMiddleNameProperty",
    @"kABPersonPrefixProperty",
    @"kABPersonSuffixProperty",        
    @"kABPersonNicknameProperty", 
    @"kABPersonFirstNamePhoneticProperty",
    @"kABPersonLastNamePhoneticProperty", 
    @"kABPersonMiddleNamePhoneticProperty", 
    @"kABPersonOrganizationProperty", 
    @"kABPersonJobTitleProperty", 
    @"kABPersonDepartmentProperty", 
    @"kABPersonEmailProperty", 
    @"kABPersonBirthdayProperty", 
    @"kABPersonNoteProperty", 
    @"kABPersonCreationDateProperty", 
    @"kABPersonModificationDateProperty", 
    @"kABPersonAddressProperty", 
    // ... etc
};

- (NSString *)ABPropertyIDToString:(ABPropertyID)propertyVal {
    return ABPropertyID_toString[propertyVal];
}

- (ABPropertyID)stringToABPropertyID:(NSString *)propertyString {
    int retVal;
    for(int i=0; i < sizeof(ABPropertyID_toString) - 1; ++i) {
        if([(NSString *)ABPropertyID_toString[i] isEqual:propertyString]) {
            retVal = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Then pass `stringToABPropertyID:` the value from the array `[self.allKeys objectAtIndex:j]` and you will be returned an `ABPropertyID`:

```
currentFieldProperty = [self stringToABPropertyID:[self.allKeys objectAtIndex:j]];
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for your detailed answer.
For some reason I get (ABPropertyID)[[self.allKeys objectAtIndex:j] intValue]; as (null)

Comment: @GuyDor You might have an empty string in `[self.allKeys objectAtIndex:j]`.  Do an `NSLog(@"%@", [self.allKeys objectAtIndex:j]);` and see what it prints out.

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", [self.allKeys objectAtIndex:j]); - "kABPersonPrefixProperty"
NSLog(@"%@", currentRecord); - "First"

I created a contact in the Simulator with first name of "First" and last name of "Last" and it prints me "First" for every property

Comment: @GuyDor That is probably because when you pass the int value of the string property name from your array to `ABRecordCopyValue`, it gets interpreted as `kABPersonFirstNameProperty` (which should be an `int` of `0`).  You need to convert the string object in the array to an `ABPropertyID` before passing it to `ABRecordCopyValue`.  See my edits.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and patience, I'll reward you soon

Comment: @GuyDor Happy to help.  If you run into any more issues with this code join up in this chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4298/room-for-chown-and-guy-dor and i'll try to help out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting my earlier comment as an answer:

I would especially give thought to the value of currentFieldProperty - because it is taken out of a dictionary, it is an object but the function is supposed to receive an enumerated value. Maybe try

```
currentFieldProperty = (ABPropertyID)[[self.allKeys objectAtIndex:j] intValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

Several problems:

- ABPropertyID is not an object type. `(ABPropertyID)[self.allKeys objectAtIndex:j]` is clearly wrong. I'm not sure how it's even possible to be "an array of all properties (each property as string)". What string are you talking about? Where did you get this string from? If you are talking about the string of the name of the property e.g. `@"kABPersonEmailProperty"` then it would be pretty much impossible to get the value of it from that.
- ABPropertyID values like `kABPersonEmailProperty` are not constants. They are variables, and they only seem to be initialized after you initialize an address book for the first time.